# Whats the easiest way to construct MongoDB with database forms?

Tags: html, forms, mongodb

Looking for a shortcut to create a mongoDB Model, Forms, Form Elements etc, as I'm lazy and currently have to hand craft all the Schemas, etc and tie it all together manually in code... Isn't there an easier way to generate all this front to back, thats not already wrapped up inside a CMS?

Comment: What is your preferred programming language/stack? Can you elaborate on your requirements: are you looking for a visual design tool, code generator, scaffolding, or something else? For example, you can generally find Object-Document Mappers (ODMs) for popular languages which will significantly reduce the amount of repetitive boilerplate code you need to write (eg  [Mongoose ODM](http://mongoosejs.com/) for Node.js). There are also data modelling tools which can generate ODM or driver code based on different sources like ER diagrams or reverse engineering an existing deployment.

Comment: I wanna say this is in the direction of the answer I'm looking for, and is a fitting reply because I find myself using different languages, and a general answer like this gets the gears rolling in the right direction. But for the sake of specifics of what I'm using, I am using a MEAN stack.

Comment: Aside from preferring the MEAN stack your requirements aren't significantly clearer yet. However, I suspect you're looking for something like [KeystoneJS](http://keystonejs.com) rather than a GUI tool. Keystone is a non-opinionated framework which builds on Express & Mongoose to create a form-driven admin UI which can also be used as a RESTful backend. For example, your model can declare a field as a [`Date` type](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#fieldtypes-date) which then enables a date picker in the UI and associated validation. You can easily customise & extend.